# Where is the install script located in the Magento folder?

Tags: install, script

As sometimes my 2,5 yr old production site will redirect for unknown reasons to the install page I would like to know where the install script is located in the Magento folder. This way I can delete it for avoiding security breaches. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you delete or rename `install.php` in your root.

Also make sure there's a valid installation date in your `app/etc/local.xml` and that the file is readable. This is used by the Mage class to check if it was installed.

Answer (score 2):

What version are you using?

Typically you will be redirected to the install page if `app/etc/local.xml` is not found.

See `Mage::isInstalled()`

```
/**
 * Retrieve application installation flag
 *
 * @param string|array $options
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isInstalled($options = array())
{
    if (self::$_isInstalled === null) {
        self::setRoot();

        if (is_string($options)) {
            $options = array('etc_dir' => $options);
        }
        $etcDir = self::getRoot() . DS . 'etc';
        if (!empty($options['etc_dir'])) {
            $etcDir = $options['etc_dir'];
        }
        $localConfigFile = $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';

        self::$_isInstalled = false;

        if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
            $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
                self::$_isInstalled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return self::$_isInstalled;
}
```

If it's determined it's not installed, you will be redirected to `.com/index.php/install`

```
header('Location:' . self::getUrl('install'));
```

Which is where the `Mage_Install` module takes over.